# Why do you need to clean a boar guinea pig's genitals?

Tags: grooming, guinea-pigs

Apparently, boar pigs need their bits maintained [every three weeks](http://www.guineapigtoday.com/2012/07/09/tips-your-male-guinea-pigs-routine-boar-cleanings/).

Why?

What do they do in the wild?

http://www.guinealynx.info/impaction.html

https://www.theguineapigforum.co.uk/threads/boar-care-bits-bums-baths.135661/

Comment: To be honest,  I've been breeding cui for years and never knew about this. Never had any problems in my males regardless of age. My expectation is that if you feed properly and they get the exercise they need they should be fine.

Comment: The first sentence in the linked source is "Older boars may develop a condition called impaction", key word is "**Older**", in the wild they don't live long enough to be "Older"

Comment: @JamesJenkins If you look at all three articles (and other stuff on the webs) there are many people who seem to think it is just a fact of life for caring for boars, not just old boars like me.

Comment: @abalter I just glanced at the first line.  I probably should have chosen not post the comment, as I really don't know anything about it, and it kind of half a lame answer.

Comment: Tbh that sounds like they arent' getting enough water and greens..

Answer (score 1):

I tried to visit the page you linked and was unable to. For what it's worth, I have a 3 year old boar and I have never cleaned his genitals. I have occasionally removed a sharp piece of hay from that region, very carefully, but nothing else. He's a fighter and very fussy and it's a battle just to clip his nails, so I try my best to avoid any additional torture. That being said, if this is very important to boars' health as they age I should learn how to do it.